# Plane and span Vector

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following problem: the plane equation is given by $x_1-2x_2+4x_3=0$ I need to come up with the two vectors that spans the plane. So the normal from the equation can be written as $(1,-2,4)$ So $(1,-2,4)$ has to be equal to the cross product of two vectors:

$$1=a_2b_3-a_3b_2$$
$$-2=a_3b_1-a_1b_3$$$$ 4=a_1b_2-a_2b_1$$

So I take the random approach and set $b_1$ to $0$, so I obtain $\frac{b_3}{b_2}=\frac12$.So $b_3=1$, and $b_2=2$. If I replace these values in the system, I obtain $a_1=2$, $a_2=3$, $a_3=1$. So two vectors can be span ($[2,3,1]$ and $[0,2,1]$). However, the answer in the back of the book is different. Can someone explain where I make mistake?

Comment: There's no error. There's an infinity of pairs of spanning vectors.

Comment: What are the answers in the back of book? Perhaps the spans are the same, but they wrote the vectors in the basis as some linear combination of your vectors?

Comment: jl00, it is  [-4 0 1 ] and [2 1 0]

Comment: Bernard thanks very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in comments, there’s an infinite number of solutions to this problem. However, observe that for any nonzero vector $(a,b,c)$, the vectors $(0,c,-b)$, $(-c,0,a)$ and $(b,-a,0)$ are all orthogonal to $(a,b,c)$, and at least two of them are nonzero. (These vectors are the cross products of $(a,b,c)$ with the standard basis vectors.) Their negations are, of course, also orthogonal to $(a,b,c)$.

So, for your normal vector $(1,-2,4)$ We can immediately find three nonzero vectors orthogonal to it: $(0,4,2)$, $(-4,0,1)$ and $(-2,-1,0)$. The second of these and the negation of the last one give you the book’s answer.